# Rewrite rules for EDD product page

Tags: wordpress, url, easy-digital-downloads

I want my url changes depending on the term of taxonomy category_download custom post types download.

**Example:**

I have 2 categories:

– plugins

– themes

I wish I had a url for my single download:

/plugins/name_of_download/

AND

/themes/name_of_download/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this code to your themes functions.php file,

```
function __custom_messagetypes_link( $link, $term, $taxonomy )
 {
     if ( $taxonomy == 'plugins' ){

            return str_replace( 'plugins/', '', $link );

     }
     else if ( $taxonomy == 'themes' ){

             return str_replace( 'themes/', '', $link );    
     }
     else{

             return $link;
     }

 }
add_filter( 'term_link', '__custom_messagetypes_link', 10, 3 );
```

I am assuming the used slug, May be you have to change the your taxonomy slug if these are different.

If have any problem you can freely ask, Thanks,

Comment: I am using edd_slug function as product.